# Fonts look different on different iOS versions

Tags: objective-c, ios, uifont

I am building an application that will run on iOS versions 4.0 and above. At some point i use UIFont for some labels in the following way:

```
UIFont *labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helveticaneue-bold" size:14];
```

The problem that i face is that on iOS versions 4.0 and 4.1 are smaller than on versions 4.2 and 4.3

Any idea why this occurs and how i can resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might sound stupid but as soon as i posted the question i had an inspiration so i will answer my own question in order to help other people that might face the same problem

Comment: The font is technically HelveticaNeue-Bold, perhaps different iOS versions have different case sensitivity semantics?

Comment: You are right... i was typing my answer when you posted your comment :)